# Bash: Error when storing result of unix command to variable in while loop

Tags: bash, unix

I have the following script called test.sh:

```
echo "file path is : $1"
path=$1
while read -r line 
do
    num=$($line | tr -cd [:digit:])
    echo num
done < $path
exit 0
```

I am attempting to grab the digit at the start of each line of the file stored as $path. the end result will be to loop over each line, grab the digit and remove it from the file if it is less than 2.

Every time i run this loop i get the error "./test.sh: line 5: : command not found. What part of the while loop am I doing wrong? Or is it something to do with the tr command?

Comment: You need `num=$(echo "$line" | tr -cd [:digit:])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can spot a few things wrong with your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "file path is : $1"
path=$1
while read -r line 
do
    num=$(tr -cd '[:digit:]' <<<"$line") # use here string to "echo" variable to tr
    echo "$num" # added quotes and $
done < "$path" # added quotes, changed $dest to $path
```

In summary:

- `cmd <<<"$var"` (here string) is a bash built-in designed as a replacement for `echo "$var" | cmd`. I added `#!/bin/bash` to the top of the script, as I am using this bash-only feature.
- I have quoted your variables to prevent problems with word splitting and glob expansion.
- I made the assumption that you really meant to use `$path` on the last line (though I may be wrong).
- Finally, there's no need to `exit 0` at the end of your script.

Comment: `[:digit:]` should be quoted to avoid the shell expanding it to matching filenames.